# Doctrine Query on Many to One relationship

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Padel project on Symfony2 I have a Competition - Registration relationship

On the "Competition" entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Registration", mappedBy="competition")
 */
protected $registrations;
```

On the "Registration" entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PadelSchedule\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="registrations")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idPlayer", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $player;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Competition", inversedBy="registrations")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idCompetition", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $competition;
```

Something like this. What I need to do is, having the id of the player, get a list of the competitions on which this player is registered.

The close thing that I have get is using a join with this query:

```
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('r, c')
            ->from('PadelScheduleMainBundle:Registration', 'r')
            ->leftJoin('r.competition', 'c')
            ->where('r.player = :idPlayer')
            ->setParameter('idPlayer', $idPlayer);
```

But as it seems by the error I get, what I think I get through this is a list of Registrations with the competition joined, but I need for my view is a list of "Competition" objects.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you select from your Registration entity you get a result of Registrations. Maybe you have better luck using a query like this:

```
$em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c')
    ->from('PadelScheduleMainBundle:Competition', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.registrations', 'r')
    ->where('r.player = :player')
    ->setParameter('player', $playerId)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your query question.. I have write this query ..Please **Try** with this query:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT c
     FROM PadelScheduleMainBundle:Competition c
     INNER JOIN c.registrations r
     WHERE r.player = :idPlayer')
->setParameter('idPlayer', $idPlayer);
```